# Voice to text Convert by Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using BluetoothHeadset Class for converting voice to text by Bluetooth headset. so i am getting an error in bluetoothprofile.servicelistener which is not working in android 2.2 or api level 8.

How to give its support for 2.2.

i don't want its should be working in 2.2 but at least my app will not force close in below api level 11.